# Leaked Retrofit call causes UI to go blank

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I use Retrofit and RxJava for network calls. For the first time I ran into a weird problem. For one of the calls the following error message is displayed:

HTTP FAILED: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

But the call is started from the main thread and it's the same result even if I remove any calls in onNext. So it must be something in the call, which is a  solo call! This is the call in a presenter:

```
public void updateEmail(final String newEmail) {
  disposables.add(AccountRepository.updateEmail(newEmail)
  .retry(1) 
  .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Reply>() {

    @Override
      public void onNext(Reply reply) {
    }
    @Override
      public void onError(Throwable e) {
    }
    @Override
      public void onComplete() {
    }
  }));
}
```

And this is the Repository call:

```
public static Observable<Reply> updateEmail(String email) {
  return getMyApiService().updateEmail(email)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

And the Retrofit interface called MyApiInterface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(UrlMap.apiProfileUpdateEmailUrl)
Observable<Reply> updateEmail(@Field("email") String email);
```

Nothing unusual, I have more than 100 calls like this.

Now if I add retry(1) as above, the call goes through, but the first call seem to be leaked, because it's still in the threads in the Network Profiler.

Furthermore, The call happens in a Fragment in an Activity with bottom navigation. If I switch to another fragment, all the calls there finish in the background without error, but the UI is not updated, I see a blank screen. But if I navigate to another activity and back, the UI is updating again.

The disposables is a CompositeDisposable object and it's cleared when the presenter is unbound. Disposable.clear in onNext() doesn't help.

I added five interceptors to the client for logging, headers, etc. Maybe they cause this somehow? Or something else? I'm trying to fix this for more than a day, but couldn't get much closer to the solution.

Comment: Are any of your intercepters touching UI elements -- either setting or getting?  Any exceptions in your intercepters will be sent up to the retrofit level.  A complete stack trace for the exception would help narrow things down.

Comment: @iagreen Indeed, I turned off one of the interceptors and the leak is gone it seems. This one is used to obfuscate images if the user hasn't verified their email address yet. It doesn't touch the UI directly though, only sets a flag... in a list adapter. Ugh. I will investigate this further once I'm back at work after Easter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a listener for user verification changes -- that are coming from all the response headers -- in the main feed, so we can obfuscate the images. I wrapped the listener in a runOnUiThread() method and the leak went away.